# MySQL best practice naming conventions

Tags: mysql

Consider these simple tables:

```
id primary-key, auto-increment
name varchar(256)
+---------+
- tasks   -
+-------------------------------------------+
- id      |  name                           -
+-------------------------------------------+
- 1       |  Go to supermarket              -
- 2       |  Buy cheese                     -
- 3       |  Buy PS4 and not Xbone          -
+-------------------------------------------+

id primary-key, auto-increment
username unique varchar(128)
+---------+
- users   -
+-------------------------------------------+
- id      |  username                       -
+-------------------------------------------+
- 1       |  dalejr                         -
- 2       |  firstnamelastname              -
+-------------------------------------------+

user_id fk, index
task_id fk, index
+---------------+
- users_tasks   -
+-------------------------------------------+
- user_id      |  task_id                   -
+-------------------------------------------+
- 1       |  1                              -
- 1       |  2                              -
- 2       |  3                              -
+-------------------------------------------+
```

- I always lowercase my table names and column names
- I always use 'id' instead of 'task_id' unless it is a foreign key. I think `tablename.tablename_id` is stupid.
- I always index foreign keys like the users_tasks table

**How does this practice differ from established MySQL convention / best-practice?**

And more importantly, **... is it bad?**

Comment: I don't think there is a "standard convention".  Your way looks perfectly fine to me.  As long as you are consistent in all your tables, you're good :)

Comment: I totally agree with Rocket...

Comment: In my experience your current practice is the best one. If you're using this convention, pretty much everything is straightforward. When somebody opens the `user_tasks` table he'll know that `user_id` is a relation to `users.id`. I usually would name the `id` column in `users` as `user_id` just because it's easier for someone new on the team to start right away. And I agree with @RocketHazmat as well.

Comment: @ChrisG.  I have voted to close this question.  You are asking open ended questions about religion (in a sense), which isn't appropriate here.

Comment: Ok. I got my answer :)